# Installing MobileFirst 7.0 server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

Are there any instructions for installing MobileFirst Server 7.0 on AWS EC2(Amazon Web services). I found this article (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_install_worklight_server_on_amazon_ec21?lang=en), but it seems outdated for latest versions.
I would really appreciate if anyone has some generic document for installing MobileFirst on Cloud services like AWS.

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 is not different than Worklight 6.2 etc, it's the same but with new features, etc.

You setup your account for an EC2 VM, which is running Linux, and MFPF supports Linux. Nothing is different from that perspective.

Meaning, the blog post you've found is true also for MFPF 7.0.